# Asynchronous Flow Charts. How to visually represent asynchronous logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, promise

Yes, it's a bit of an oxymoron.

Is there a visual language for representing asynchronous logic?  Something as simple as a flow chart?

I'd like to model UI "screens", and the logic behind them.

Thanks!

Comment: It would just be a flowchart with concurrency, i.e. multiple active flows - compare NFA vs DFA. Also have a look at petri nets, wich are explicitly used to model concurrent logic, but they might be a bit overcomplicated (depends on your use case).

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but what really happens with `ajax` callbacks (or `setTimeout`, or any other 'asynchronous logic') is that when it fires it is added to the event queue, then executed once the event loop gets to that spot. So rather than representing it visually via control flow you might instead draw a representation of the event queue and have things feeding it. Note that this is slightly different than concurrency and very different than parallel threads.

Comment: The biggest decision you face with diagramming techniques is how they are going to be used. There are two basic schools of thought - (1) to get you started then, once the initial code is cut, forget about them, or (2) for the life of the software, maintain the diagrams as configuration-controlled items (eg as part of a suite of Design Documentation) and only ever make changes to the code in response to changes in the diagrams (etc). The second regime will probably be unfamiliar to anyone who has not worked for a large public/corporate customer (particularly the military).

Comment: @Roamer-1888: There's also a third one: Generate the code automatically from the diagrams. It might be not common yet and is still explored in academia, but offers a new basic idea.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want some combination of Data Flow Diagrams (DFD for data sources/processes/stores), and State-Transition Diagrams (STD for modelling the various states of the UI). IIRC, one of the interesting rules of a DFD is that asynchronous processes must inter-communicate via a store, which can be a strong driver of system hardware architecture.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, good point. In that regard, UML deserves a mention ... as indeed you have done below :)

Comment: I don't understand - first of all standard UML charts have syntax for async actions. Second of all - I'd normally just represent them as synchronous actions. Promises proxy values - just use whatever you'd use for that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I'm coming to the slow realisation that "asynchronous" is used in two rather different ways; (1) where there are two or more *continuous, independent* processes, which are async with respect to each other, and (2) *spawned* async processes, which are the type we mean when talking about Promises. Before about 2009, I had only ever thought of asynchronism in terms of (1) though I'm sure that spawned async processes must have existed prior to that. I mention this because I believe it is only type (2) async actions that might be represented as synchronous as you suggest above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "visual language" for representing asynchronous logic: Petri Nets.

### [Petri's] Net Theory

A Petri Net is a description of a system in terms of net elements. There are four types of net elements: place, transition, input and output. An input connects a place to a transition. An output connects a transition to a place. Each net element may have zero or more annotations. Each annotation may have zero or more annotations too.

### Type Annotations

A net element has a type: P (Place), T (Transition), I (Input), O (Output)

### Icon Annotations

A place element may be visually represented by a circle. A transition element may be represented by a square. An input element may be represented by an arrow from a circle to a square. An output element may be represented by an arrow from a square to a circle.

### Label Annotations

Every circle or square may be accompanied by a label identifier, text used to uniquely identify the shape. The label for a square is centred in the square. The label for the circle is outside the circle.

### Patterns and Classes

It may be convenient to begin with an existing set of annotation patterns -- such as the types of annotations used in Place/Transition nets, a class of Petri Net.

1. Every place has a mark -- quantity or number from 0.
2. Every transition has a status -- true or false.
3. Every input has a status -- true or false.
4. Every input has a weight -- a quantity or number from 1.
5. Every input has a status update rule/logic-- if the mark of the input place is greater than or equal to the weight of the input, the status is true; otherwise, the status is false.
6. Every input has a weight update rule/logic -- subtract the input weight from the mark of the input place.
7. Every output has a weight -- a quantity or number from 1.
8. Every output has a weight update rule/logic -- add the output weight to the mark of the output place.
9. Every transition has a status update rule/logic -- the status of the transition is true if the status of each of its input is true; otherwise, the status if false.
10. Every transition has a mark update rule/logic -- call on the mark update rule of every input and every output.

### "Extensions"

If the type of annotations presented above are unsatisfactory for an application, annotations may be added or changed. For example,

1. Change the shapes that represent the net elements.
2. Modify the update rules/logics.
3. Alter the range for the input weight and change the status update rule for inputs – for Inhibitor Nets, another class of Petri Net, the input weight may be a number from 0; the status update rule has an additional component, if the input weight is zero, the status is true if the mark of the input place is zero, else the status is false.
4. Add a label annotation for every input weight whose value is greater than 1 or whose value is 0.
5. Etc.

Comment: Interactive examples: http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/TGI/PetriNets/introductions/aalst/

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to "*model your (asynchronous) logic*", so that you could derive semantically sound conclusions from it, then you need [petri nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net). From Wikipedia:

> A Petri net is a modeling languages for the description of distributed
>   systems, with a graph of transitions and places.
>   Like industry standards such as UML activity diagrams, BPMN and EPCs,
>   Petri nets offer a graphical notation for stepwise processes that
>   include choice, iteration, and concurrent execution. Unlike these
>   standards, Petri nets have an exact mathematical definition of their
>   execution semantics, with a well-developed mathematical theory for
>   process analysis.

Promises should be easily representable in a petri net as 3 places, each denoting [one of the states](https://promisesaplus.com/) of a promise.

If you are just looking for a simple visual representation of your system, you might be looking for a [data flow diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram). Or you just extend your flow chart with concurrency primitives like "spawn async process" and "await result". If you're looking for a properly specced "visual language", have a look at OMG's [UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) tools, e.g. the [state machine diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine).

Answer (score 0):

I've used this library for a project, to visualize states of database-objects: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-state-machine-es6

While it does not really cover async stuff, it does help in reasoning about applicationlogic with non-technical people.